# Finding conflicts within lists

Tags: c#

I have this problem with logic and mapping two different tables. One table is presented to the user for them to select items from. We then need to map their selections to a bigger list of system recognized items. Some system items are combinations of user items.

User Items = 
Key | Item 
 1  | A 
 2  | B 
 3  | C 
 4  | D 
 5  | E 
 6  | F

System Items = 
SystemCode | UserItemsMapping 
EG1 | 1 
EG2 | 2 
EG3 | 1,2 
EG4 | 1,3 
EG5 | 2,3 
EG6 | 4 
EG7 | 5 
EG8 | 5,6 
EG9 | 3 
EG10| 4,5,6 

So if the user enters A, B, C, D, E, F  [=  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 in keys] as their input. The system should be able to determine conflicting mappings.
Selected items **A, B & C** are in conflict, please select from following: 
EG3 (1,2) + EG9 (3) or 
EG4 (1,3) + EG2 (2) or 
EG5 (2,3) + EG1 (1) 
Selected items **D, E & F** are in conflict, please select from following: 
EG8 (5,6) + EG6 (4) or 
EG10 (4,5,6)

This is all done in C# using Lists and custom classes for the table contents, e,g List and List.

Edit:
So what I've managed to do is this: 
1) Get all system codes that has any of the user items in it. 
2) All system codes that have more than user item goes to one list. All combo codes goes to another. 
3) Loop through the combos list and if a user item is in against more than one system code add that to a conflict list.

So now I have a list of conflicts like this:

[code]

```
public class ConflictSets 
{
   public List<SystemCodes> SystemCodesList {set; get;}
   public List<int> UserCodesList {set; get;}
}
public class SystemCodes
{
   public string Code {set; get;}
   public string UserItems {set; get;}
}
```

[/code]

The problem is that my List ConflictSetsList only has pairs of the conflicts in it. So for the above example:
ConflictSetsList[0].SystemCodesList[0] = EG3
ConflictSetsList[0].SystemCodesList[1] = EG4
ConflictSetsList[1].SystemCodesList[0] = EG3
ConflictSetsList[1].SystemCodesList[1] = EG5
ConflictSetsList[2].SystemCodesList[0] = EG4
ConflictSetsList[2].SystemCodesList[1] = EG5

What I really want is a class that has this: 
ConflictSetsList[0].Options[0].SystemCodesList[0] = EG3
ConflictSetsList[0].Options[0].SystemCodesList[1] = EG9
ConflictSetsList[0].Options[1].SystemCodesList[0] = EG4
ConflictSetsList[0].Options[1].SystemCodesList[1] = EG2
ConflictSetsList[0].Options[2].SystemCodesList[0] = EG5
ConflictSetsList[0].Options[2].SystemCodesList[1] = EG1

Does that make more sense? Sorry I'm not very good at explaining this.

This is from data coming from these inputs:
dtSystemCodes = new DataTable. Where Row["UserInputKeys"] = xx|yy
dtUserItems = new DataTable. Where Row["Key"] = xx
List inKeys = new List() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

Thank you.

Comment: What's the issue? What did you try?

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to logically do the lists. What I've tried is this: get all systemitems, loop through and find all codes that has a user input key associated. Then go through that list and add all combinations to a separate class. I want another class called ConflictSets that will list all the affected conflicts and their associated system codes.

Comment: Show what you've tried by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to make a 2d bool array with all mappings of lenght of [1 + 2^number of examples,number of examples]

```
valid  EG1 EG2 EG3 ... EG10 

0       0  0    0       0    
1       0  0    0       1
        ...
1       1  1    1       1
```

(0=false,1=true)
in the for loop test each row for validity and put results in fisrt column
then in the fisrt column you have list of all possible mapping shemes